# Релятивность в mysql php и ползунки диапазонов

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется две связные таблицы

```
filter (id, title)
filter_values (filter_id, title)
```

Выводится эта связь следующим образом:

**Марка:**

Toyota
Audi

**Объем:**

3л
2л

Собственно вопрос, как теперь правильно с точки зрения релятивности вывести Jquery UI ползунки? К примеру хочу вывести ползунок диапазона с ценой, и ниже ползунок диапазона расхода топлива.
Как правильнее организовать таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Можно значения записывать прямо в таблицу, скорость выборки если у Вас будет 100000 записей не упадёт.

Выводить тогда цену и расход в фильтр запросом `select max(title), min(title) from filter_values where filter_id = 1`

Лучше конечно цену вынести в отдельную таблицу или хранить в таблице с товарами.

Всё зависит от Вашей текущей схемы данных:

- Если Вы в таблице с товарами храните ещё какие то данные, то лучше цену в эту таблицу поместить, но если вы на странице товара выводите цену вместе с остальными свойствами, то лучше эти данные хранить в таблице свойств
- Если Вы по цене этой ещё и в корзину класть будете, то лучше для цены завести отдельную таблицу.